# ConstraintLayout and height greater than or equal

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

What I'm trying to achieve is pretty simple, yet I cannot manage to output it.

I want a simple layout with an icon of fixed width and height and a text on the right. Easy peasy.

I also want to center the text vertically with respect to the icon. Also this is easy.

When the text is short and stays in a single line everything is perfect. When the text is longer, the problem arises.

With this code:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_icon"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. "
        app:layout_constraintHeight_min="48dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/icon" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

one line text is displayed as desired, longer text is hidden when overflows the 48dp

What is wrong in the code and in my knowledge?

Thanks

Comment: did you try height with wrap content

Comment: @ManojMohanty yes, with no desirable result

Comment: `I also want to center the text vertically with respect to the icon. Also this is easy.` So you mean your current implementation correctly centres the text relative to the icon ?

Comment: I tried myself textview expands if you set its height to wrap content with min height of 48dp do you have any other parent view for ConstraintLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below layout.

- Here we are making the TextView's height independent of ImageView by
  making the textView `android:layout_height` as `wrap_content`.
- and here both TextView and ImageView are placed in central_vertical relative to parent instead of each other.

  ```
  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/icon"
      android:layout_width="48dp"
      android:layout_height="48dp"
      android:scaleType="fitXY"
      android:src="@drawable/ic_icon"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/title"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. "
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/icon"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
  ```

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem and opened my eyes

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_icon"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. "

            app:layout_constraintHeight_min="48dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/icon"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"

            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

btw you can use `TextView`'s `android:drawableStart` attribute

Comment: Using drawable inside the textview is surely an option to consider. For now, because of databinding, I stick with my idea. But thank you, because also your answer gave me the desired result

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that `ConstraintLayout` will only apply `layout_height="wrap_content"` to the items that have horizontal constraints set to `parent`.

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

Try this code and see if it's how you want your layout to look like

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_nav_settings"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:text="The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I choose Pavan answer because with it's explanation I understood my error. But both are a valid answer so thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here we are making `TextView` height as `match_parent`, Try this

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_user"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. "
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a good way to use TextView. I suggest use TextView like this:

> android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>
> android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
> android:textSize="20sp"(desired textSize)
>
> app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"

The constrained width tells the textView to respect its Start and End constraints.

Comment: It's about the height not the width

Comment: Use constrainedHeight . Same behaviour. But as you said. When the text should take 2 lines it does not. So, you have to use constrainedWidth.